# PHP Session variables do not retain their values between pages

Tags: php, session

My PHP codes work the same it should on my computer but it is not working on the server.  On the server, the session variables do not retain their values between pages.  I had contacted the web hosting company and they insisted this was a coding issue.  But I don't seem to be able to find what is wrong with my codes; after all, they work perfectly fine on my computer.

To simplified the codes, I have two test pages set up to see what is going on.

page1.php

```
<?php
    $timeout = 1440;
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $timeout);
    session_name("admin");
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['var1'] = "asdfasdf";

    echo session_id() . "<br>" . $_SESSION['var1'];

?>


<a href="page2.php">Page 2</a>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
    session_name("admin");
    session_start();


    if (isset($_SESSION['var1'])) {
      echo session_id() . "<br>" . $_SESSION['var1'];
    } else {
      echo session_id() . "<br> NOT exist.";    
    }

?>


<a href="page1.php">Page 1</a>
```

On my computer, when I ran page1.php, it shows the value of the session ID and then the value of $_SESSION['var1'] as asdfasdf.  I clicked Page 2 and it shows the same values on the screen.  However, on the server, when I ran page1.php, it shows the value of the session ID and then the value of $_SESSION['var1'] as asdfasdf.  I clicked Page 2.  It shows the same session ID but it shows "NOT Exist" meaning that $_SESSION['var1'] does not exist.

On page2.php, I tried adding error_reporting(E_ALL) but the web hosting server throws a 500 error.  It appears that they don't allow changing the level of error reporting.

I show the phpinfo both on my computer and on the server.  The only major difference I can see is that I am running php 5.5 and the server has php 5.4.  Can this be the reason why the server does not retain the session variable value?  If so, how can I correct this?

In case you want to see the behavior for yourself, please go to [page1](http://www.monteandjanicechan.com/foundation/page1.php) and you can click on Page 2 on the page to see what I am talking about.  You can also view the php info on the server by going to [Server PHP info](http://www.monteandjanicechan.com/foundation/info.php)

Comment: try removing all whitespace before `session_start()`

Comment: Have you checked phpinfo to see if you have sessions enabled on the server ?

Comment: @adeneno Yes, Sessions are enabled on the server

Comment: @sean9999, I just did but that did not help

Comment: if you have access to session files check it yourself that whether session is writing on file or not and if you have not access to files ask web hosting to check it for you.

Comment: It looks like your hosting is running on a Windows server. PHP might not have permission to write to the session file path.

Comment: there is one more difference in php.in it says that your server is using wincache. However I don't think that might be causing the issue

Comment: To check whether its actually storing the session or not you can check if isset condition in page1.php to make sure its actually storing the session on server

Comment: please remove the line session_name("admin");  and try.

Comment: @versalle88, I contacted my web hosting company to check on the permission issue.  They switched the hosting server to Linux and made some other changes.  Now, things are working as expected.  Thank you very much for your help!